# How to insert data to table when one of the columns is set to current timestamp on insert?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `date` column of type `datetime` and I want it to update to the current date and time on every insert.

I set the column to `Default Value or Binding = (getdate())`

But still, the code itself throws an error about it:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@date".

This is the query:

```
SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table VALUES(@name, @phone, @date)", SQLCon);
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
```

I also tried to completely omit `@date`:

```
SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table VALUES(@name, @phone)", SQLCon);
```

But then I get this error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

When I changed the `id` column to `identity`, it stopped asking me to declare the scalar variable `@id`, but that didn't help with the date column.

Comment: If you give the column a default value then you don't *need* to `INSERT` into it. Though in the snippet you give us, not only do you not define `@date`, you don't define `@phone` or `@name`; where are the definitions of your parameters?

Comment: Did you try `INSERT INTO table (NAME, PHONE) VALUES (@name, @phone)`? (in the first parenthesis, tell which columns you are providing values)

Comment: sorry, I updated the post now. I gave the column default value of `getdate()`, it's in the post (I did it via the MS Management Studio). `@phone` and `@name` are just values from inputs, but I tested it and it works and inserts the data

Comment: So you need to omit the column from your `INSERT` and *define* the columns you want to `INSERT` into (which you should be doing anyway), as @Rafalon shows you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, when you want to insert a row but only fill specific columns, you need to tell which columns:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (NAME, PHONE) -- <- tell which columns
VALUES (@name, @phone)
```

If you don't do this, there is no way it can *magically* guess what value goes in which column